# change the key "DONE"

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need to change the key "DONE" on the keyboard;
using this property

```
myTextView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
```

is there a way to enter a customized text?

and is there a way to do make it grey like the keyboard and not blue?

thanks

Comment: resolved UIReturnKeyDefault :)

Comment: Post it as an answer and flag it as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved UIReturnKeyDefault :)